# Slurm installation: munge SSH test returns permission denied

Tags: ssh, slurm, munge

I'm doing my first Slurm install from scratch on a 2-node Ubuntu cluster (1 head, 1 worker)
I followed those instructions for Munge installation ([here](https://github.com/SergioMEV/slurm-for-dummies#controller-node) and [here](https://www.bodunhu.com/blog/posts/set-up-slurm-across-multiple-machines/), pretty similar) ; munge is active on each node but when I do the recommended test `munge -n | ssh <remote node> unmunge` I get a  `Permission denied (publickey).`

Why am I seeing this? Before installing munge, is there a requirement that the munge user or some other user should be able to SSH to the other node from both nodes? How to fix this problem?

SSH is installed on both nodes, and the same `munge.key` is present at `/etc/munge` on both nodes

Comment: Skip the `munge` and check that the given user you have been using can `ssh -vvv <remote_node>`. For example `root` is often not permitted to ssh into from a remote machine.